# Tranpose mysql data with php

Tags: php, mysql

I haven't posted here much but I use the site all the time. For years I have found what I needed or an example to modify. Thank you for that. Maybe I am just tired tonight but I need some head formatting MySQL data using PHP.

My current query returns data that looks like this:

```
 league_id  | complex_location        |  complex_id  | complex_field

00000000015 | Savage Sports Complex   |  00000000001 | Savage South

00000000015 | Savage Sports Complex   |  00000000001 | Savage North
```

I am using the following query to get the data in the format above:

Query:

```
select a.league_id
     , b.complex_location
     , b.complex_id
     , c.complex_field 
  from wp_lm_leagues a 
  left 
  join wp_lm_sports_complex b 
      on b.complex_id in(a.complex_id_1,a.complex_id_2 a.complex_id_3,a.complex_id_4,a.complex_id_5) 
left 
join wp_lm_sports_complex_fields c
  on b.complex_id = c.complex_id 
where a.league_id = 15
```

I want the data to be transposed like so:

```
league_id  | complex_location      | complex_id  | complex_field | complex_field2

00000000015| Savage Sports Complex | 00000000001 | Savage South  | Savage North
```

Comment: You could get close using GROUP_CONCAT, but the fields would in on one column with commas between. If there is another column in the fields table that would indicate which column to put it in, it's possible (but not pretty) to get what you are looking for. It might be better to use the GROUP_CONCAT and split them in PHP. That would code that would be easier to maintain, and less likely to break if your data changes

Comment: Btw, 00000000015 = 15.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of rewriting your query for legibility. But note that any time you have enumerated columns, you can be certain that your schema is under-designed

Answer (score 0):

Use the GROUP_CONCAT() function. Try this query

```
SELECT a.league_id, b.complex_location, b.complex_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(c.complex_field SEPARATOR ', ') AS complex_field FROM wp_lm_leagues AS a
LEFT JOIN wp_lm_sports_complex AS b ON 
(a.complex_id_1 = b.complex_id or a.complex_id_2 = b.complex_id or 
 a.complex_id_3 = b.complex_id or 
a.complex_id_4 = b.complex_id or a.complex_id_5 = b.complex_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_lm_sports_complex_fields AS c ON b.complex_id = c.complex_id
WHERE a.league_id = 00000000015 GROUP BY a.league_id
 ORDER BY a.league_id, b.complex_location
```